# Ionic3 Cursor Missing on TextBox when Centered Content on iOS Simulator

Tags: html, ios, ionic-framework, ios-simulator, ionic3

When using Ionic 3 and centering an `ion-content`, the cursor on an `ion-input` is not on screen.

The desired output contains a
[cursor on the text-box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJmGp.png)
but upon centering the content using the following CSS:

```
.vertical-align-content > * {
     display: flex;
     align-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
```

the output is centered, but when clicking the password field, the [cursor is not present.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFBCu.png)

The following html is used as the general format:

```
<ion-content class="vertical-align-content">
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <form (ngSubmit)="login();">
                <ion-item margin-bottom>
                    <ion-input no-margin placeholder="Email Address" name="username" [(ngModel)]="user" focus-next type="email"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item no-lines>
                    <ion-input no-margin type="Password" name="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="pass"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <button ion-button type="submit" id="logon" >Log On</button>
            </form>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

This can only be found using an iOS Simulator. For testing, I have been using an iOS 11 iPhone X. This issue was only present after updating to ionic 3.

This can be replicated with a fully clean new project, with the same code given.

I have tried using full `ion-grid` layouts as well as using no grid and just full CSS to center, but they both present the same issue.

Anything helps, irritating bug.
Thanks.

Comment: can you please put your code using https://stackblitz.com

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-x9ktd6 @core114 Not too sure how this will help since this is an iOS Simulator / Device issue only. Works fine in chrome, etc.